# How to identify multi-word expression in a sentence without a predefined multi-word list

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying to identify every multi-word expression in a sentence and tokenize that sentence. For instance, the example input sentence is "In short, this merchandise is in short supply." and I wish the output could be shown as below:

```
['In short', ',', 'this', 'merchandise', 'is', 'in short supply', '.']
```

I have already achieved the aforesaid result by using a predefined list and the following python code.

```
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import MWETokenizer

multiwordExpressionList = [("In", "short"), ("in", "short", "supply" )]  ## this is a predefined list 
sentence = "In short, this merchandise is in short supply."

mwe = MWETokenizer(multiwordExpressionList, separator = ' ')
resultList = mwe.tokenize(word_tokenize(sentence))
print(resultList)
```

However, the drawback is quite clear. This program need a predefined multi-word expression list to identify whether any multi-word expression exist in a sentence. Is there any suggested python package, module or method can identify any multi-word expression exist in a sentence ?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options: either use some existing models (e.g. Stanza which also supports MWE https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/mwt.html) or if you have enough data build your own MWE model using for example Gensim: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html. I have used the second option fairly successfully.